# Surface analysis with R - Shape recognition

Tags: r, geostatistical-analyst, surface

I am trying to analyse a geological surface with R & Python and I would like to know if there are some ways to distinguish, divide and quantify repetitive structures such as advertised by a software company (picture below).

I don't have a precise scope but I would like to understand what shapes are repeating themselves onto the analysed surface.

Are there advised packages that could be useful to accomplish this task?

[image: Analyze surface texture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, you can use library `raster` and the different `terrain` function or your custom `focal` functions.
- Using `terrain` with `slope` will give you information on the local slope
- with `TPI` will tell you if you are on a crease, a hill or a plate area.
- Using `focal` (potentially combined with `aggregate`), you can calculate some TPI with larger scope, or pass a Gaussian filter, ...

With these different indices, you can then apply some pixel classification, with PCA like proposed in your illustration or any other classification procedures like randomForest, ...

Comment: This is a great insight. Thanks.

I am dealing with the point cloud first. Would you just consider a final mesh-reconstruction (rasterised) or xyz points could be useful as well?

Comment: The tools developed specifically for rasters are really interesting. They are also made to work correctly with your computer memory while loading only what is necessary. So I would find the adequate resolution, and work with rasters.